# Full screen reading in new mendeley reference manager?

Tags: mendeley

Mendeley Desktop has been updated to Mendeley Reference Manager. However, I noticed that the full-screen reading function is no longer available. With the current layout, multiple top bars occupy approximately 30% of the screen while reading. Are there any possible ways to enhance the reading experience?